# Object::connect: No such signal

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qobject

I have a problem to create custom slots/signal with a struct. I have the following code:

```
qRegisterMetaType<namespace::myClassA::aStruct>();
QObject::connect(&myClassA, SIGNAL(theSignal(myClassA::aStruct)),
                 &myClassB, SLOT(theSlot(myClassA::aStruct)));
```

When running the program I got:

```
Object::connect: No such signal NameSpace::myClassA::theSignal(myClassA::aStruct)
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'NameSpace__CLASSNAME')
```

How do I resolve this problem?

PS: The slot and the signal have been properly declared in header files using the `Q_SIGNALS` and `Q_SLOTS` keywords, with the correct argument (`aStruct`).

Comment: Did you run `qmake` after implementing the signal and slot?

Comment: Q_DECLARE_METATYPE/qRegisterMetatype isn't needed nor will it help for direct connections (the default when both objects live in the same thread)

Comment: It occurs to me that even what could look like little tiny pinpricks, can hinder proper functioning: SIGNAL(PageClosed(QWidget *page)) has generated an error. I removed the parameter: page, and it was accepted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Types used in signal/slot connections must be fully 'scoped' because the method call is converted into text, so your connection call should look like this:

```
QObject::connect(&myClassA, SIGNAL(theSignal(namespace::myClassA::aStruct)),
                 &myClassB, SLOT(theSlot(namespace::myClassA::aStruct)));
```

You'll probably  have to update the signal/slot declaration arguments to match.

Comment: You just released me from the awful hell that is troubleshooting signal/slot connections.  Thank you kind sir (or madam)

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution of signal slot:
The declaration and call of signal and slot functions were mismatching! As soon as I fixed them, the slot got called.

Here you may got all the possible way of mistake.

[**20 ways to debug Qt signals and slots**](https://samdutton.wordpress.com/2008/10/03/debugging-signals-and-slots-in-qt/)

Hope, it helped a lot after reading this articlethis and will save your time.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the slot/signals, you can base the namespaces of the argument structure like so:

::namespace::ClassA::structA

Rather than using ClassA::structA from inside 'namespace'.  This is useful if you are trying to reference a structure inside the same namespace.